# JAXB xml ordering or Sequence or property ordering

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xml-binding

i want to marshal my object in a ordered xml.
My jaxb class is given below:-
i have used Xmlordering but it doesn't work to order my xml.

```
package mypackage;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

import mypackage.TourplanAvailabilityRequest.OptionInfoRequest.RoomConfig;
import mypackage.TourplanAvailabilityRequest.OptionInfoRequest.RoomConfigs;
import com.eos.hotels.data.HotelSearchQuery;
@XmlRootElement(name = "Request")
@XmlType(propOrder={"request"})
public class TourplanAvailabilityRequest {
    private OptionInfoRequest request;
    public TourplanAvailabilityRequest() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public TourplanAvailabilityRequest(HotelSearchQuery hsq) {
        this(hsq, "null");
    }

    public TourplanAvailabilityRequest(HotelSearchQuery hsq, String optInfo) {
        OptionInfoRequest req = new OptionInfoRequest();
        req.setAgentID("AATRAV");
        req.setPassword("AATRAV");
        req.setOpt("citycode???????");
        req.setInfo("GS");
//        req.setDateFrom(Calendar.getInstance().setTime(hsq.startDate));
//        req.setDateTo(Calendar.getInstance().setTime(hsq.endDate)   );
        req.setRateConvert("N");
        req.setReturnWarnings("N");
        req.setCompressReply("N");
        RoomConfigs roomsToBook = new RoomConfigs();
        List<RoomConfig> rooms = new ArrayList<RoomConfig>();
        for (int i = 0; i < hsq.rooms.length; i++) {
            RoomConfig room = new RoomConfig();
            room.setAdults(hsq.rooms[i].adults.length);
            room.setChildren(hsq.rooms[i].children.length);
            room.setRoomType(hsq.m_roomType);
            rooms.add(room);
        }
        roomsToBook.setRoom(rooms);
        req.setConfig(roomsToBook);
        this.request = req;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "OptionInfoRequest")
    public OptionInfoRequest getRequest() {
        return request;
    }

    public void setRequest(OptionInfoRequest request) {
        this.request = request;
    }

    public static class OptionInfoRequest {
        private String      agentID;
        private String      password;
        private String      opt;
        private String      info;
        private Calendar    dateFrom;
        private Calendar    dateTo;
        private String        rateConvert;
        private String        compressReply;
        private String        returnWarnings;
        private RoomConfigs config;

        @XmlElement(name = "AgentID")
        public String getAgentID() {
            return agentID;
        }

        public void setAgentID(String agentID) {
            this.agentID = agentID;
        }

        @XmlElement(name = "Password")
        public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }

        public void setPassword(String password) {
            this.password = password;
        }

        @XmlElement(name = "Opt")
        public String getOpt() {
            return opt;
        }

        public void setOpt(String opt) {
            this.opt = opt;
        }

        @XmlElement(name = "Info")
        public String getInfo() {
            return info;
        }

        public void setInfo(String info) {
            this.info = info;
        }

        @XmlElement(name = "DateFrom")
        public Calendar getDateFrom() {
            return dateFrom;
        }

        public void setDateFrom(Calendar dateFrom) {
            this.dateFrom = dateFrom;
        }

        @XmlElement(name = "DateTo")
        public Calendar getDateTo() {
            return dateTo;
        }

        public void setDateTo(Calendar dateTo) {
            this.dateTo = dateTo;
        }

        @XmlElement(name = "RateConvert")
        public String getRateConvert() {
            return rateConvert;
        }

        public void setRateConvert(String rateConvert) {
            this.rateConvert = rateConvert;
        }

        @XmlElement(name = "CompressReply")
        public String getCompressReply() {
            return compressReply;
        }

        public void setCompressReply(String compressReply) {
            this.compressReply = compressReply;
        }

        @XmlElement(name = "ReturnWarnings")
        public String getReturnWarnings() {
            return returnWarnings;
        }

        public void setReturnWarnings(String returnWarnings) {
            this.returnWarnings = returnWarnings;
        }

        @XmlElement(name = "RoomConfigs")
        public RoomConfigs getConfig() {
            return config;
        }

        public void setConfig(RoomConfigs config) {
            this.config = config;
        }


        public static class RoomConfigs {
            private List<RoomConfig> room;

            @XmlElement(name = "RoomConfig")
            public List<RoomConfig> getRoom() {
                return room;
            }

            public void setRoom(List<RoomConfig> room) {
                this.room = room;
            }
        }

        public static class RoomConfig {
            private int    adults;
            private int    children;
            private String roomType;

            @XmlElement(name = "Adults")
            public int getAdults() {
                return adults;
            }

            public void setAdults(int adults) {
                this.adults = adults;
            }

            @XmlElement(name = "Children")
            public int getChildren() {
                return children;
            }

            public void setChildren(int children) {
                this.children = children;
            }

            @XmlElement(name = "RoomType")
            public String getRoomType() {
                return roomType;
            }

            public void setRoomType(String roomType) {
                this.roomType = roomType;
            }

        }

    }
}
```

i want my xml output to be look like this:-

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Request SYSTEM "hostConnect_3_00_000.dtd">
<Request>
 <OptionInfoRequest>
  <AgentID>AATRAV</AgentID>
  <Password>AATRAV</Password>
  <Opt>BKKACAMARIA??????</Opt>
  <Info>GS</Info>
  <RateConvert>Y</RateConvert>
        <RoomConfigs>
            <RoomConfig>
                <Adults>1</Adults>
                <Children>0</Children>
            </RoomConfig>
            <RoomConfig>
                <Adults>1</Adults>
                <Children>0</Children>
            </RoomConfig>
        </RoomConfigs>
 </OptionInfoRequest>
</Request>
```

My current xml is:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Unicode" standalone="yes"?>
<Request>
    <OptionInfoRequest>
        <AgentID>AATRAV</AgentID>
        <CompressReply>N</CompressReply>
        <RoomConfigs>
            <RoomConfig>
                <Adults>1</Adults>
                <Children>0</Children>
            </RoomConfig>
            <RoomConfig>
                <Adults>1</Adults>
                <Children>0</Children>
            </RoomConfig>
        </RoomConfigs>
        <Info>GS</Info>
        <Opt>citycode???????</Opt>
        <Password>AATRAV</Password>
        <RateConvert>N</RateConvert>
        <ReturnWarnings>N</ReturnWarnings>
    </OptionInfoRequest>
</Request>
```

someone can guide me where i am wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using propOrder on outer class i have used it on inner class,& it works like charm.

```
@XmlType(propOrder={"agentID","password","opt","info","dateFrom","dateTo","rateConvert","compressReply","returnWarnings","config"})
    public static class OptionInfoRequest {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use the `propOrder` property on the `@XmlType` annotation for each class you want to control the ordering.

Comment: Thanks Blaise.
somehow i solved it few minutes ago.
Will post my answer as well.